# Restaurar Base de Datos Postgres

Tags: postgresql

tengo una aplicación en c# deseo hacer el Backup y Restore desde la misma aplicación en un base de datos postgres, pero he aquí varias dudas, para esto usare la linea de comandos.

1. Backup ok, ahora al hacer la restauración se puede hacer sobre una db que tiene sus tablas creadas? a mi me manda error que ya existe varios constraints entre otros errores.. Pero cuando hago el restore  con solo la db creada sin tablas la restauración es ok.
2. Depende de la pregunta 1, si para hacer el restore necesito la db sin tablas, entonces no podré hacer el restore desde la aplicación, ya que tendré que eliminar las tablas de la base existente. O existe alguna forma de hacerlo.

Mis comandos:

```
pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --format custom --blobs --verbose --file E:\test.backup pventa

pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --dbname pventa --verbose E:\test.backup
```

Answer (score 1):

*... ahora al hacer la restauración se puede hacer sobre una db que tiene sus tablas creadas?*

Cuando restauras una BDD PostgreSQL, se hace en 3 secciones, primero el esquema (osea la creación de tablas y demás), posteriormente los datos, y al último los constrains.

Si tu tienes ya tablas en una base de datos, te marcará errores desde la creación de las tablas, osea que las tablas ya existen, esos errores los ignorará, pero cuando intente cargar los registros como los constrains ya existen en las tablas que ya estaban creadas, te marcará aún mas errores porque los datos no se cargan de forma ordenada y obvio si no coinciden las dependencias entre los registros no se cargarán.

*Depende de la pregunta 1, si para hacer el restore necesito la db sin tablas, entonces no podré hacer el restore desde la aplicación, ya que tendré que eliminar las tablas de la base existente. O existe alguna forma de hacerlo.*

Aquí dependerá si necesitas que las tablas no se borren y se vuelvan a crear cuando hagas el restore, pero si no tienes problema con ello, puedes aplicar "clean" cuando hagas el restore, utilizando estos parámetros:

pg_dump:
  -C, --create                 incluye órdenes para crear la base de datos

pg_restore:
  -c, --clean                  tira (drop) la base de datos antes de crearla

- Donde al crear el dump especificas que se añade la sentencia de crear la Base simplemente con el -C

  pg_dump.exe **-C** --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --format custom --blobs --verbose --file E:\test.backup pventa
- ya al restaurarla le incluyes el -c, lo que hará es borrarte la base y el dump la crear antes de restaurar los datos.

  pg_restore.exe **-c** --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --dbname pventa --verbose E:\test.backup

De caso contrario, no puedes cargar un dump con tablas preexistentes, por lo que te explico. Espero te funcione!

Saludos!